How can I prevent a webpage from displaying a bookmarklet's javascript text in the URL bar after running it?
I have a bookmarklet written in the form javascript:(function(){ [do some stuff to current page]; })(); that I run from Firefox.  It acts on the webpage as intended, but running it replaces the website's URL in the URL bar with the text of the bookmarklet.
Searching around for solutions it seemed as though pushState() or replaceState() should do the trick(?),  but I can't figure out how to implement them correctly.
I've tried adding history.replaceState({},'',window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname); as the last line inside the bookmarklet's function(){}, but still the javascript text shows up in the URL bar instead of the URL specified by replaceState() after running.  Duplicating or refreshing the window afterwards confirms that search queries in the original URL have been removed, so replaceState() is apparently working, but the text of the URL bar still isn't being updated to match it.
EDIT: From the comments to this question I've realized the problem wasn't linked to running the bookmarklet per se. It happens only when calling a bookmarklet directly from the URL bar by keyword, with the obvious workaround of not calling it that way. I am still curious, though, if there is any way to invoke a bookmarklet by keyword without replacing the URL bar with its javascript after it runs?
From the link in the comments I can see that, for good security reasons, there is no way to freely overwrite the URL bar text with whatever you'd like, but is there any way to force the text in the URL bar to 'refresh' itself to the active page's current window.location.href without forcing a full page reload?

The accepted answer here might help.

I frequently use bookmarklets. They don't alter the URL bar. I do nothing at all to prevent URL bar changes, which makes me wonder what you're doing that alters the URL bar. Would you provide the whole bookmarklet for us to debug?

@Nanigashi Reading your comment gave me the head slap moment to realize where I was going wrong: I'd set the bookmarklet up with a keyword for convenience (having only learned about keywords for opening bookmarks in the act of figuring out how to set up the bookmarklet and deciding to try it out), and until now I've only ever run it by overwriting the URL with that keyword. In that context that the keyword gets replaced by the javascript text of the bookmarklet. So all I have to do to preserve URL is select it from the menu instead. I am embarrassed. Thanks for the inspiration, though!

Glad I could help.
